# Blender IK constraint not working correctly

Tags: rigging, bones, inverse-kinematics

I made a rigged character but when I wanted to add IK constraint to it, the rotation of bones became confusing : [image: Image of my character with IK]

I searched youtube for the answer but the only thing that I found is changing the `Pole Angle` of the IK constraint.

I did it but the `foot` bone was steel in wrong direction.
I also tried changing the `role` of bones. and none of them worked.

Blend file : [.blend file](http://www.filehost.pt/2MPg2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In *Edit* mode, move the knees and the pole targets a bit forward. The knees need to be bent a bit so that Blender knows how the legs are supposed to bend, and for the moment your pole targets are too close to the knees. Once done, correct the *Pole Angle* to something around -100°.

[image]